# how to make condition work based on check box check and Uncheck using angular2 reactive forms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a checkbox and i had done it using `[(ngModel)]`, it is working fine.
Now i want to use the same inside form so i wrote html in this way:
But here, if the checkbox is checked, then it is not storing in cookie, nothing is working. I am not getting where i am struck too.

Answer (score 0):

In reactive forms you don't send data in ngSubmit method, because they exist in the component.

So in your case in html you have `(ngSubmit)="login()"`

And in the controller in the `login()` method you access the filled values as:

```
const password = this.loginForm.value.password;
const saveUserName = this.loginForm.value.saveUserName;
```

Comment: Here, if the checkbox is checked, then it must save password as default

Answer (score 0):

i think thats happen because the param you send in your first line html file is into the form now, so you cant send as a single param

```
login(loginForm.value,saveUserName)
```

it seems the variable 'saveUserName' doesnt exist, you must refer it through the form, actually you no longer need to pass parameters in your function because is all into the form,

```
if (this.loginForm.saveUserName == true) {
```